# Power notification wakes up laptop from sleep but it disappears immediately

Tags: 17.10, lenovo, thinkpad

Good evening everybody,

I have noticed recently that when my laptop goes to sleep when idle, it wakes up sometimes and it shows a power notfication, however the moment I move the pointer to click and see more details it disappears. I have not noticed any change in battery life or performance. Anybody knows anything about this?

Thanks for helping me out,
Jurgen

Answer (score 2):

That notification should say "`Computer will suspend very soon because of inactivity.`"

This misleading power notification message has been reported as a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1709194).